# How can i access public swift file in xcframwork ios?

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, xcframework

I have problem with xcframwork.when i create xcframwork my properties not display in my main project storyboard. When i create framework it display all properties in my storyboard.

I have created Following code

```
@objc 
public extension UIView  {
        // Note  : Corner radius and shadow not work both side by side so you need to outlet and set layer radius
        // other wise you can set layer.cornerradius in user defines
       
        //MARK: Border COLOR
        @IBInspectable
        var borderColor: UIColor? {
            get {
                return self.borderColor
            }
            set {
                self.layer.borderColor = newValue?.cgColor
            }
        }
    }
```

**1 using framework**

[image]

It display all Properties

[image]

now i created xcframework. all properties not display Now i am stuck with this.

anyone help me how can i create xcframwork and display all properties like normal framework. Please help me on this.

Comment: As this might be project settings related would it be possible for you to provide access to project to investigate?

Comment: yes i give you project after sometime for investigating

Comment: @Asperi you got any solution

Answer (score 0):

The properties in your framework are internal. When no access modifier is specified then Swift defaults to internal.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOmVl.png)

so in your code:

```
var radTopLeft:CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
```

is equivalent to:

```
internal var radTopLeft:CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
```

Therefore no code outside the framework can access this property. In order to make it accessible to the framework consumer you have to mark the property public. i.e.

```
public var radTopLeft:CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
```

Test it out: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_WSGKRKNt4lytrVEuozn8W4WYRR6nPif/view?usp=sharing